# Checking Jquery ajax load success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been using [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) to load another page, and just using their example :

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");
```

However I want to run a function when the load is successful, and a different one if it fails, unfortunately the description on the callback says:

> The function called when the ajax request is complete (not necessarily success).

How do I make sure the load was successful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the more detailed $.ajax() method call.  This will give you more fine-grained control over the AJAX call (but it also requires a bit more work than a simple .load().)  It will allow you to call different functions based on whether your call returns success or error.

Check out: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options for documentation on this function.  If you click the "Options" tab on that page, you will get a full listing of the parameters that you can pass to the $.ajax() function.

Answer (score 22):

Check the [textStatus](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) of the response.

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li", 
  function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
         // all good!
    }
    if (textStatus == "error") {
         // oh noes!
    }
  }
```

In determination to figure out the issue:

A JSBin example of **[`success`](http://jsbin.com/ageju)** and **[`fail`](http://jsbin.com/arite)**

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I was trying to get `textStatus` to work with only `function (textStatus) {` but it looks like it only works when those 2 other variables are there too. **This should be the accepted answer. :)**

Comment: Thanks, it works great. i have no idea why this is not selected as answer :/

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to your callback is the string status value for the request, which will be one of `"beforeSend"`, `"success"`, `"complete"`, and `"error"`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function and it worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "demo_test.txt", 
   success: function(result){
       location:reload();
   }
});
```