# Getting only a part of a file

Tags: jquery

I have some very simple sample code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'demo2.htm',
  success: function(loadeddata){
    $("#loaded_data").html(loadeddata);
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Loaded data currently returns everything. What I need to is to get only a specific div  and make it the html of #loaded_data.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Edit:

While trying to use .load()...

Here's what I wrote into the comment.

Thanks, your updated example is great. However I'm not sure what's wrong with mine.

This: works

```
$("#loaded_data").load("demo2.htm #mydiv", function(text, status, request) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

This:

```
$("#loaded_data").load("demo5.htm #mydiv", function(text, status, request) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Does not. It just hangs. There is no demo5.htm But no error is returned.

Thanks a lot again for all of your help.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use load's callback.

Comment: Maybe your webserver is not returning a 404 or something equivalent for a non-existent page...?

Comment: Ahah, yes, that could be it, since I'm not running a server, just doing this in a simple folder on my desktop. I'll go test it, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.load()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) for this:

```
$("#loaded_data").load("demo2.htm #mydiv", function(text, status, request) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

If this isn't working for you, you're doing something wrong and we'd need to see some more code.

Here is a sample of getting a single div [from this page](http://jsbin.com/ekari) to [this page](http://jsbin.com/ajopi) using the code above.

Comment: Sorry, is there some way to do the same with .ajax? I've tried .load, but was unable to get success/error to work correctly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936357/checking-jquery-ajax-load-success

Comment: You were first here, and also went through the trouble of the example. Nice.

Comment: Thanks, your updated example is great. However I'm not sure what's wrong with mine.

This: works

$("#loaded_data").load("demo2.htm #mydiv", function(text, status, request) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});

This: 

$("#loaded_data").load("demo5.htm #mydiv", function(text, status, request) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
});

Does not. It just hangs. There is no demo5.htm

Comment: Mark: Here is an example of it linking to a URL that doesn't exist: http://jsbin.com/ihafo - it gives me error just fine. Perhaps it's something to do with your webserver?

Comment: Could be, I'm not on a server though, just trying to edit in a folder on my desktop. Would that make a difference? But well, so long as it works on a server I'll be happy then. Thank you very much, and thanks for your patience.

Comment: OK, some further thoughts. But $.ajax correctly returns the error even though it's also not on the server, so that's why I'm inclined to like it more.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my other example, but I'll clone it into this question which is probably questionable (no pun intended)... but alas, we've got two questions for the same thing...

Check the [textStatus](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) of the response.

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li", 
  function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
         // all good!
    }
    if (textStatus == "error") {
         // oh noes!
    }
  }
```

In determination to figure out the issue:

An example of success:

http://jsbin.com/ageju

An example of fail:

http://jsbin.com/arite

Comment: Ah you slick one. I'll upvote you here too because I'm nice. ;)

Comment: Though it would have been nice to learn how to get just a part of the return. Oh well :P some other time I guess.

I selected you as the correct answer on the other question. Thanks!