# Wait for .load to finish and then do something

Tags: jquery

I'm loading an external script through `.load('url')` and need to wait for it to finish so I can update the source of an image.  Sometimes load is fast enough that the image reload applies, but most of the time it takes too long and the image reload happens first, so the image doesn't actually change.

Comment: using deferred object http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ or load's callback

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add a callback function:

```
$('#yourElement').load('yourUrl.html', function() {
  /* When load is done */
});
```

More to read at http://api.jquery.com/load

Answer (score 29):

`load` method has callback function that is executed when the request completes. I think you should use it.

Comment: You know, I had used .load to test before and it didn't work.  Used it again and it does what I had expected it to do.  Guess I had a typo before that didn't break syntax.  Oh well, thanks.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered here on how to capture the success event of a load function:
[Checking Jquery ajax load success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936357/checking-jquery-ajax-load-success)