# Use text from one page in another page

Tags: html, css

Using only HTML and/or CSS (not JavaScript), I would like to use text from one page in all other pages, so that if I change the information on the index page, all other pages will update.
Currently, the text is in a paragraph `<p>` within a `<footer>`.

I know that this can be done with JavaScript, but I want to do it with only CSS/HTML.

index.html:

```
.MyText:before {
  content: "Text here: ";
}
```

other page(s):

```
<div id="//index.html/MyText">   <--- is something like this even possible?
```

Comment: Not possible with vanilla HTML

Comment: *"but I want to do it with only CSS/HTML"* - Why?  Whoever gave you that requirement may need to clarify the approach they are expecting you to take.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Lines of HTML from a given file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351911/embed-lines-of-html-from-a-given-file)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using a single css file with multiple html file but the text has to be in the css file not in the html file.  eg:

```
.shared-class::before {'
  content: "something here"
} 
in index.html <p class="shared-class"></p>
in another.html <p class="shared-class"></p>
```

there is no way to share a text in a html file with other html file with out javascript.

Comment: It actually can work but it isn't answer for the question: >if I change the information on the index page, all other pages will update. Currently< So your code can set the content but it can't change the content.

Comment: [Please don't use the CSS content property to insert non-decorative information, because that content won't be accessible to everyone.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F87)

Comment: Thank you all, but Abrham - That is kind of how I ended up making it work;
I made a style.css file and simply put the following in it:

footer::before {
   content: "my text";
}
Then, since the footer was going to be the same on every page, I just added a <footer>