# Organize HTML sites with Bootstrap 4 Navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

**TLDR:** What is the standard/best practice to organize the different HTML sites/files, when using a navigation bar, that should be visible on every site?

**Background:** I'm starting for the first time to create a website. It should run on an ESP and I got some good results with Bootstrap 4. I've defined a Bootstrap navbar, just like in all the examples (for example [here on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp)). Though the examples only use do-nothing links; they don't show how these links are commonly used with the navbar and the different files (this must be a general principle, that I don't know).

The navbar should of course be visible on every site, while the content below it should change according to the clicked link. When I simply use a link in the navbar to a different html file without a navbar included it is of course not visible.

**How are the different sites normally organized in relation to the navbar?**

I have thought of different possibilities:

- Having a navbar in every file (obviously a nightmare to maintain)
- Having the navbar in an extra file, including it somehow in every other file
- Managing all the content in the main file together with the navbar, including the other content files somehow

At my current knowledge I just don't know enough, so I also don't know what to search for. If there are already good information about this on the web, can you please provide me with search words or links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use `HTML` then there is no other choice. You need to add a `navigation bar` to each page which is a nightmare as you have mentioned. But if you are planning to use `server-side programming` languages like `PHP` then they provide a keyword called `include`. Its syntax is  `include 'filename'` now you can add a `file` like `header.php` inside `include` folder and you can use across multiple pages. [You can have a look in this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)
.But if you are using `NodeJS`, `ExpressJS` then they have their own `templating-engines` like `ejs`, `handlebars`, `pug`. They consist of `partials` So, that partials can be use across multiple pages. [Here is the link for partials](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-blocks)

Comment: Great, thank you. I will go with PHP here. I found a good example website at github, that I can change for my purpose. I will add an answer with my chosen way.

Comment: Ok, command back. Found out, that I cannot run PHP on an ESP (all the results, that I've seen previously only where about doing a web request to a PHP site, that runs elsewhere). That means, that I'm stuck with client site programming, so javascript. I guess I could load other HTML files via javascript into the main site, basically creating the same structure, but managed client site.

Comment: I will leave this answer marked as correct. It answered my question. Will add the answer with the further information, when I have confirmed, that I can really do this via javascript

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer of kedar sedai is the correct one, I want to add my chosen way and further information as documentation for future readers.

kedar sedai is right, that I need to use some programming language. One problem is, that I cannot use server side programming languages, because the ESP does not support them. So I needed to move to client site programming, thus javascript.

I used the solution of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837835/include-html-in-another-html-file) to include another HTML file. I now serve only the main HTML file, which contains the navbar and the following part to load the correct HTML file dependent on the `page` parameter in the URL:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="content" style="display:block;overflow:visible"><br>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      var url = new URL(window.location.href);
      var c = url.searchParams.get("page");
      if(c != null){
        $("#content").load(c+".html");
      }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

This works like a charm and I now have notion how I can organize my html files to be displayed with the navigation bar.