# jquery not firing the error event on 403 when loading new src for img

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a page which includes a static Google map. When the page is resized I dynamically change the map. I have the following code in a function which is fired on page resize and periodically after a check that the sizes of elements on the page match :

```
if (imageDownloadEnabled) {
   url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + userLat + ',' + userLng + '&zoom=14&size=' + ((theWidth/2)|0) + 'x'+ ((theHeight/2)|0) + '&sensor=false&scale=2';
   newImage = $('<img />');
   console.log('Retrieving map from ' + url);

   newImage.error( function() { 
      console.log("error loading image");
      imageDownloadEnabled = false;
   }).load(function(eventObject) {
      console.log("done loading image");
      console.dir(eventObject);
      $('#maps-image').replaceWith(newImage);
      newImage.attr('id', 'maps-image');
   }).attr('src', url);
/**/
} else {
   console.log('disabled');
}
```

When the google maps api overloads (happening at the moment because a bug of mine caused an infinite loop) I get a 403 error and a substitute image. The error event handler is not called though.

Is there any way around this? I'd like to make sure that in the event of a 403, the page stops requesting new images from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with in the end, after looking around.

The problem is that Google is returning an image along with the 403 status, so the onload event is fired. So my code would load the 10px by 10px error image, regardless of the size of the div it sat in.

The trick was to use an in-memory Image(), load the url and check the size of the image in the onload event. If the image is too small, load the standin.

The code :

```
if (imageDownloadEnabled) {
    url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + userLat + ',' + userLng + '&zoom=14&size=' + ((rightWidth/2)|0) + 'x'+ ((rightHeight/2)|0) + '&sensor=false&scale=2';
    oldMap = $('#maps-image');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        if(this.width < 100 || this.height <100) {
            console.log('Google 403, loading standin');
            /*  disable image download */
            imageDownloadEnabled = false;
            oldMap.attr('src', standinUrl);
        } else {
            oldMap.attr('src', url);
        }
    }
    img.onerror = function() {
        console.log('Error, loading standin');
        oldMap.attr('src', standinUrl);
    }
    img.src = url;
} else {
    oldMap.attr('src', standinUrl);
}
```

In case it is not clear, below a certain browser size I get rid of the map, which is why I simply check for image size in the onload function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the complete callback function of .load and check the textStatus value

```
.load($url,function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if(textStatus=="error") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Just found a similar question with response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936357/checking-jquery-ajax-load-success

Comment: No, this is not the load ajax call, which loads html from an external source. This is the load event handler, which gets called when the event happens (the src attribute is changed). http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: But I agree with the principle of what you are saying. I passed the eventObject to the function but it doesn't contain the status code.

Comment: Are you running this code in a local file? quote from the jquery docs "Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol."

Comment: No the image is coming from the google static maps api, and the backup from our server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the load bit if you just want to know if an image failed to load, the below example works for me:

.error() is a shortcut for .bind('error', handler).

The preset src loads fine, once its loaded (documentready) jquery attempts to replace it with an invalid file and falls back to the google logo if it can't

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#foo-image").error(function(){
                    alert("error loading image, substituting...");
                    $(this).attr("src","http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
                }).attr("src", "missing.png");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold;">
        <img id="foo-image" src="http://www.iskin.co.uk/wallpapers/imagecache/ipad/union_flag_wallpaper.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```